# Are foreign currency bank accounts in Brunei protected by deposit insurance?

Tags: banking, foreign-currency, deposit-insurance, brunei

All retail banks in Brunei are members of the Brunei Darussalam Deposit Protection Corporation (BDPC). The deposit insurance scheme protects up to 50,000 BND per person per bank in the event of a bank collapse (source: [BDPC FAQ](https://www.mofe.gov.bn/Divisions/bdpc-faq.aspx)). Does this protection apply to foreign currency bank accounts?

Comment: The table under "_Q. If I have deposits in different branches of the same member institution (bank), will all my deposits be protected separately?_" in that FAQ lists a "_Foreign currency fixed deposit_" account as being protected (albeit in an example of how protection is across all accounts with an individual institution), so I would _guess_ the answer is yes (provided the account is with an institution that has a full banking license), but don't know with certainty (hence not an answer).

Comment: The *Deposit Protection Order, 2010* is probably the authoritative reference for this issue.

Comment: Based on my reading of the legal text, it appears that foreign currency bank accounts are covered by the deposit protection scheme, but I am not a lawyer.